# Calculated Columns - Comparing multiple columns with IF statement

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column

I am fighting with SharePoint calculated columns and trying to compare multiple columns.

The SharePoint list has the following columns:

- Completed Date - Date
- Completed - Yes/No
- Due Date - Date
- TodayDate - Date
- Overdue - Calculated

I am trying to do the following:

- When "Completed Date" is blank "Overdue" value = "n/a"
- When "Due Date" is greater than "TodaysDate" the "Overdue" value = "Yes"
- When "Completed" equals TRUE the "Overdue" value = "No"

I've got this far, but the "Yes" part isn't working

```
=IF(AND([Report Completed]=TRUE),"No",IF(OR(ISBLANK([Report Completed Date])),"n/a",IF(AND([Report Due Date]>Today),"Yes")))
```

Any help gratefully received.

Rob

**UPDATE**

I just noticed I missed part of the "When "Due Date" is greater than "TodaysDate" the "Overdue" value = "Yes" condition.  It should have been this:

- When "Due Date" is greater than "TodaysDate" AND "Completed" = FALSE the "Overdue" value = "Yes"

Comment: Try using this -
IF(ISBLANK([Report Completed Date]),"n/a",IF([Report Due Date]>Today),"Yes",IF([Report Completed]=TRUE,"No")) and let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the Today date in calculated column, you should use `Today()` instead of `Today`.

Besides, you don't have to use `AND(),OR()` function to wrap your condition. This should work for you:

```
=IF([Report Completed]=TRUE,"No",IF(ISBLANK([Report Completed Date]),"n/a",IF([Report Due Date]>TODAY(),"Yes")))
```

Updated:

```
=IF([Report Completed]=TRUE,"No",IF(ISBLANK([Report Completed Date]),"n/a",IF(AND([Report Due Date]>TODAY(),[Report Completed]=FALSE),"Yes")))
```

Comment: Thanks Michael - your comment about removing AND/OR function made me realise I had mis-typed one of the conditions, so I've updated the thread with correct condition requirement.

Comment: I have updated my answer, check if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks Michael, that helped a lot!